# Giving same answer to a question which is already answered and getting upvotes

Tags: discussion, answers, upvotes

I have answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104127/how-to-change-a-given-controls-properties-via-code/28104173#28104173). I have seen that the person who has given an answer to the question has written precisely what I have written. And also got an up-vote.

If questions can be marked as duplicate, then why can't answers be? Don's I deserve the up-vote? Shouldn't peer reviewers notice this?

Comment: Marking answers as a duplicate is dangerous. Because sometimes answers are too similar to each other and you just can't stop that, answer is answer. Also the chance of asking similar question at the same time is very low, but the chance of giving similar answer at the same time is really high.

Comment: Well it does contain the same content. Right?and what about the upvote?

Comment: see [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773) at MSE

Answer (score 1):

In this case answers went an about 30 min ago, it seems to be really duplicate.

But if **Aravind** had opened more tabs, there was no answer when he read the question and after answering other questions (30 mins ago) he started to write this answer and didn't see if sb. wasn't faster. Just didn't reload a tab or didn't see the actual answers number.

On the other hand I don't see a reason why to delete or flag similar answers. Is problem that you answered and get upvote and sobebody answered something similar and got upvote too?

If I answer whatever and anybody put there similar answer, I stay absolutely calm.